# Error using Blueprint xml to establish a Weblogic component with a JndiObjectFactoryBean

Tags: xml, weblogic, blueprint

So, I'm trying to get a Weblogic component to work in our application's blueprint file using the snippit below, though I'm not sure what else to include about it other than it being used to connect to a JMS queue.

```
> <bean id="wmqjndiFactoryBean"
> class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
>         <property name="jndiName" value="jms/ConnectionFactory"/>
>         <property name="jndiTemplate">
>             <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
>                 <property name="environment">
>                     <props>
>                         <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
>                         <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost</prop>
>                         <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">weblogic</prop>
>                         <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">weblogic</prop>
>                     </props>
>                 </property>
>             </bean>
>         </property>
>         <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
>         <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
>     </bean>
>     <bean id="weblogic-jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
>         <property name="configuration">
>             <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
>                 <property name="connectionFactory" ref="wmqjndiFactoryBean"/>
>             </bean>
>         </property>
>     </bean>
```

And this exception occurs:

```
    org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error setting property: PropertyDescriptor <name: connectionFactory, getter: class org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getConnectionFactory(), setter: [class org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory)]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:941)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:933)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:668)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to convert value org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean to type javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.AggregateConverter.convert(AggregateConverter.java:184)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.convert(BlueprintRepository.java:402)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.convert(ReflectionUtils.java:394)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$MethodPropertyDescriptor.internalSet(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils$PropertyDescriptor.set(ReflectionUtils.java:378)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:939)
    ... 29 more
```

And after scouring the internet for hours over the past couple days, I have not found a solution. I can't exactly tell you what it's not because it's hard to remember what I've already tried, but most of the articles/other questions I looked at weren't even applicable.

So why is this exception occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you think it is related to duplicate jars/classes on your classpath?

Comment: When I looked, I couldn't find anything that indicated any duplication. I'll probably have to ask someone who knows the code better to double-check for me if this is definitely the problem.

Comment: @JeY did you come up with a solution for this issue?  I've come accross a similar issue, different class but same error.

Comment: Nope =\ Like I mentioned, already scoured the web for hours with no result, so I'm just waiting patiently for a reply here if one will even come up at this point.

Comment: Well, then one of my co-workers skypes me that he fixed it! I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on our team finally figured out an answer. First, they changed the route a little bit:

```
    <bean id="jmsInConnectionFactoryJndiLookupFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" init-method="afterPropertiesSet">
            <property name="jndiName" value="jms/ConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="jndiTemplate">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
                    <property name="environment">
                        <props>
                          <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
                          <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost</prop>
                          <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">weblogic</prop>
                          <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">weblogic</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="jmsInConnectionFactory" factory-ref="jmsInConnectionFactoryJndiLookupFactory" factory-method="getObject" />
        <bean id="weblogic-jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
            <property name="configuration">
            <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
                <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsInConnectionFactory"/>
            </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Second, they ran into another issue, which was solved here:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-1567

And then it was fixed, apparently! Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect! Really was struggling to get the JBoss Fuse based on Camel to integrate with Weblogic JMS. Finally with your above configuration I'm able to.